# Installing google Earth Pro on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-earth

I would like to install Google Earth Pro on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS.  I can download the .DEB file from [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/GE7/release_7_3_0/google-earth-pro-stable_7.3.0.3832-r0_amd64.deb). This is the correct file for my processor.  I can open the file in the Ubuntu software manager and choose to install the software.  No Google Earth Pro is available when I open the Dash.
How do I install Google Earth Pro?

After running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install` I get the following errors.

```
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu *codename*/main Sources                                  
  404  Not Found

Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/linuxfreedomlucid/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                            
  404  Not Found

Err:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openambit/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                              
  404  Not Found

W: GPG error: http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/dists/*codename*/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/linuxfreedomlucid/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openambit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install` and post any errors.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen.  I have added the terminal errors to my question.

Comment: Well all those 404 errors mean there is no package available. The first one "Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu codename/main Sources
404 Not Found" is a typo, "codename" should read xenial.

Comment: The public key error tells you the key to use "W: GPG error: http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45" See https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: Technically the GPG key is a waning, you can install software without the key. Fix your repos and try again.

Answer (score 0):

[16.04 64-bit Procedure](https://skagitsignal.com/how-to-install-google-earth-64-bit-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-x64/):

1. Download the following packages using your browser

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-security_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-invalid-mta_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-core_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb

2. Open Terminal and navigate to the Downloads folder (cd Downloads)
3. Install all 3 packages

   sudo dpkg -i lsb-security_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb

   sudo dpkg -i lsb-invalid-mta_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb

   sudo dpkg -i lsb-core_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
4. Fix dependency issues

sudo apt-get install -f
5. Reboot
6. Download and install Google Earth x64 .deb package

Here's the link to the download: http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html

Note: Make certain you download the 64 bit version

Open Terminal, change folders to 'Downloads' and install (sudo dpkg -i [name of .deb file])